# Scraping - inspecting element vs the soup.prettify printout

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For the following website: https://www.theice.com/products/219/Brent-Crude-Futures/data?marketId=5166946

When I inspect element for any of the contract months (Eg inspect element for "Sep22"), I see the data I am looking for (the month, eg Sep 22, Oct 22, etc) and the LAST price (106.93 in this case) is stored in a table (of class "table table-bigdata).  Specifically, each tbody element contains the requisite info I'm looking for, and then some

However, when using requests + bs4 to print the soup object eg print(soup.prettify()), I see that the data is stored in a list of dictionaries called "contracts".  The whole printout is pretty long, but for example, for the first entry, it looks something like this:

"contracts":[{"description":"Sep22","firstTrade":1423458000000,"lastTrade":1659067200000,"firstNotice":1659067200000,"lastNotice":1659067200000,"firstDelivery":null,"lastDelivery":null,"finalSettlement":1659326400000,"megawattHours":null,"optionsFirstTrade":null,"optionsLastTrade":null}]

2 questions, and they are both noobie questions, so please bear with me.

1. why is it that I can see the dictionary when I initiate a printout of the soup object, but not directly when I inspect element on the web page?
2. what would be the difference in scraping using CSS selectors derived from inspecting the web page, vs parsing out the dictionary from the soup object? Is one method better than the other? How would one even go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into it farther, it would appear the table is being 'hydrated' with data from the dictionary. Which method is 'better' depends however you define better.
If were after this data, i would call the api directly instead of trying to parse html.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://www.theice.com/products/219/Brent-Crude-Futures/data?marketId=5166946',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

params = {
    'getContractsAsJson': '',
    'productId': '254',
    'hubId': '403',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.theice.com/marketdata/DelayedMarkets.shtml', params=params, headers=headers)
response.json()
```

output:

```
[{'volume': 45308,
  'lastTime': '07/28/2022 05:06 PM GMT',
  'endDate': 'Fri Sep 30 00:00:00 EDT 2022',
  'marketStrip': 'Sep22',
  'change': 0.26261489401613314,
  'marketId': 5166953,
  'lastPrice': 106.9},
 {'volume': 239390,
  'lastTime': '07/28/2022 05:06 PM GMT',
  'endDate': 'Mon Oct 31 00:00:00 EDT 2022',
  'marketStrip': 'Oct22',
  'change': 0.08852168781351766,
  'marketId': 5166948,
  'lastPrice': 101.76}...
```

You can look on the network tab of your dev bar and look for the json being requested. And get the required parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I havent learned how to call APIs yet but I'll take a detour in my scraping studies to learn that now.  Interestingly certain elements (such as the LAST traded price) do not show up in the Page Source, but only when Inspecting element.  Is this because the browser is directly calling the API to get that value (which is why is does not show up in the Page Source?)